# Having difficulty with adding a variable to a url link in shiny uiOutput

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a link to twitter pages based on a selectInput selection. I have a data.frame, df, with columns of names and related screenNames

So in ui.R have

```
selectInput("name","Tweeter",personChoice, selected="Jane Doe"),
uiOutput('twitterLink')
```

and in server.R

```
output$twitterLink <- renderUI({

  twitterUrl <-df[df$name==input$name,]$screenName 
  print(twitterUrl #jdoe

# a("Twitter", class="web", href="https://twitter.com/jdoe") Hard code works

  paste0('a(\"Twitter\", class=\"web\", href=\"https://twitter.com/',twitterUrl,'\")')

})
```

results in the text

a("Twitter", class="web", href="https://twitter.com/jdoe") in the browser

```
tags$body(uiOutput('twitterLink'))
```

does not affect the outcome

TIA

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a function which outputs the appropriate html:

```
> a("Twitter", class="web", href="https://twitter.com/jdoe")
<a class="web" href="https://twitter.com/jdoe">Twitter</a>
```

your `renderUI` should be of the form:

```
  output$twitterLink <- renderUI({

    twitterUrl <-df[df$name==input$name,]$screenName 
    a("Twitter", class = "web", href = paste0('"https://twitter.com/', twitterUrl, '")')

  })
```

Comment: Thanks. Your actual suggestion did not appear to quite hit mark. needed closing bracket and threw up &quot; but set me on track to a("Twitter", class = "web", href = paste0('https://twitter.com/', twitterUrl)). If u want to amend answer I will credit it. Tx again

Comment: Yes that's the funny thing about non-reproducible examples they require some imagination and patience.